# How to add graphql pagination on nested object

Tags: graphql

I am writing a graphql api endpoint where I have customer details as below.

```
{
customer_name:
customer_address:
    [ 
        {
        address_1:
        },
        {
        address_2:
        },
    ]
}
```

I need to apply pagination on customer_address which is a list.

Is this possible? Or I can do it only at top level record? Please let me know what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possible by using resolver like following

```
input PageInput{
  limit: Int!
  page: Int!
}

type CustomerAddressPage {
  totalCount: Int!
  edges: [CustomerAddress!]!
}

type CustomerAddress {
  address: String
}

type Customer {
   customerName: String
   customerAddress(input: PageInput!): CustomerAddressPage
}
```

I don't know what kind of framework you use, in nestjs you can be done as follows.

```js
@Resolver(() => Customer)
export class CustomerResolver {
  @ResolveField(() => CustomerAddressPage)
  customerAddress(
    @Parent() customer: Customer,
    @Args('input') input: PageInput,
  ): Promise<CustomerAddressPage> {
    return {
    };
  }
}
```